# fullcalendar events not shown after month change (JSON feed in Angular)

Tags: json, angular, fullcalendar

I'm feeding my Fullcalendar instance on Angular with a JSON from a URL.

The GET returns 200 with well-formed JSON data, but no events are shown in the calendar.

Here is my CalendarOptions:

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    plugins: [interactionPlugin,
      dayGridPlugin,
      timeGridPlugin,
      listPlugin,],
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this),
    events: 'http://127.0.0.1:8097/event',
    startParam: 'startTime',
    endParam: 'endTime',
    timeZoneParam: 'local'
  };
```

No errors on console, just no events in the month view.

Here the JSON response of the GET API call:

```
[
  {"id":1510,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T16:15","healthServiceId":3,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":null,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"338-3248104","startTime":"2021-01-09T16:00"},
  {"id":1512,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T16:45","healthServiceId":1,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":467,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"329-9590677","startTime":"2021-01-09T16:15"},
  {"id":1513,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T17:00","healthServiceId":2,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":748,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"327-4571259","startTime":"2021-01-09T16:45"},
  {"id":1514,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T17:15","healthServiceId":2,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":592,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"348-1588967","startTime":"2021-01-09T17:00"},
  {"id":1515,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T16:00","healthServiceId":32,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":112,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"338-5994091","startTime":"2021-01-09T15:45"},
  {"id":1516,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T17:30","healthServiceId":2,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":423,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"389-4895518","startTime":"2021-01-09T17:15"},
  {"id":1517,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T17:45","healthServiceId":7,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":60,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"380-4559938","startTime":"2021-01-09T17:30"},
  {"id":1518,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T15:45","healthServiceId":3,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":829,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"349-8027366","startTime":"2021-01-09T15:30"},
  {"id":1519,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T15:30","healthServiceId":32,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":129,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"349-3404658","startTime":"2021-01-09T15:20"},
  {"id":1520,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T18:10","healthServiceId":1,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":null,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"0873-547325","startTime":"2021-01-09T17:45"},
  {"id":1521,"description":null,"doctorId":1,"endTime":"2021-01-09T18:30","healthServiceId":2,"isEventDone":false,"isRecurring":false,"patientId":716,"patientName":null,"patientSurname":null,"phoneNumber":"328-4331424","startTime":"2021-01-09T18:10"}
]
```

Comment: `with well-formed JSON data`...please [edit] your question to show that data (or a good sample of it). Perhaps some aspect of it is not in the format fullCalendar requires.

Comment: @ADyson, I've added the JSON response in the question

Comment: Ok thanks. So, I don't know if you simply haven't read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing yet, or you misunderstood it. It's very clear that the dates must be in properties called `start` and `end`. You've put them in`startTime` and `endTime` - which isn't valid unless it's a [recurring event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events).

Comment: thanks!
I haven't read that part of docs...my fault...
If you put your previous comment in an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per fullcalendar's [event parsing documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) the dates you put in your event data must be in properties called `start` and `end`.

You've put them in `startTime` and `endTime` - which isn't valid unless it's a [recurring event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events).

Comment: Just to clarify, I fetch data from a backend where the event is described as you can see in the JSON response in the question. How to map backend object to fullcalendar event object after the GET? I mean, how to map it without changing backend object property names, if possible?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform is what you need for doing that